# Conditional css class is not changing on mouseOnEnter or mouseOnOver in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to display data in table in that each row contains one info icon that should be visible on mouse hover. and we can show one pop up on clicking that info icon.(there is one onlclick method on that info button)

I have written below piece of that for that.

```
<td className="reportCard">
   {filteredVehicles.map(t =>
    <tr className="cardList" onMouseEnter={() => this.onClickReportRow(t.reportId) }>
          <span className="CardReportsName"><p className="reportNameP" >{t.reportName}</p></span>
          <span style={PreviewBtn} className={this.selectedReportId == t.reportId ? "previewBtnDisplayBlock" : "previewBtnDisplayNone"}>
                 <em className="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => this.showPopUp()} />
             </span>
        </tr>
       )}
      </td>

 onClickReportRow(reportId){
        this.selectedReportId= reportId
    }
```

So here when i am hovering on row , hovering event is called but that conditional class is not getting changed. this is working if i am using onclick method and there is no onclick in font awesome otherwise it is not working for onclick also.

this is a very weired problem dont know what exactly the issue is.

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example? What is `onClickReportRow` doing? How is `selectedReportId ` updated in order to toggle the classname?

Comment: I guess you need to provide more code what are these functions that you are caling on mouseEnter etc

Comment: what is this function doing?   -->  `this.onClickReportRow(t.reportId)`

Comment: You have written `tr` inside `td`, why so? Also, as pointed by other provide complete code.

Comment: have updated code

Comment: in this function i am just updating that variable

Comment: @DrewReese i have updated my code

Comment: @AdeshKumar i have updated my code

Comment: @Roj i have updated

Comment: @HarinderSingh i have updated

Comment: Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? A *running* codesandbox would also be excellent to live debug in, if possible.

Comment: I suspect that `this.selectedReportId = reportId;` doesn't trigger a rerender and thus your UI doesn't update the applied classnames.

Comment: @DrewReese {this.selectedReportId = reportId;} was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue is here:**
this.selectedReportId== t.reportId

**Ressolve**
this.selectedReportId is function or what?, you need to make state here to compare the repordId so that on event mouseEnter or Leave the value of state changes and can apply make changes in render

**Link**https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-turing-q4jf1?file=/src/App.js:0-1827

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />;
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredVehicles: [
        {
          reportId: 1,
          reportName: "One"
        },
        {
          reportId: 2,
          reportName: "TWO"
        }
      ],
      selectedReportId: null,
      popUp: false
    };
  }
  onClickReportRow = (ID) => {
    this.setState({ selectedReportId: ID });
  };
  showPopUp = () => {
    this.setState({ popUp: !this.state.popUp });
  };
  handleonMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({ selectedReportId: "" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <table>
          <td className="reportCard">
            {this.state.filteredVehicles.map((t) => (
              <tr
                className="cardList"
                onMouseEnter={() => this.onClickReportRow(t.reportId)}
                onMouseLeave={() => this.handleonMouseLeave()}
              >
                <span className="CardReportsName">
                  <p className="reportNameP">{t.reportName}</p>
                </span>
                <span
                  className={
                    this.state.selectedReportId === t.reportId
                      ? "previewBtnDisplayBlock"
                      : "previewBtnDisplayNone"
                  }
                >
                  {element}
                </span>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </td>
        </table>
        {this.state.popUp ? (
          <div
            class="modal fade"
            tabindex="-1"
            role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            Required PopUp
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is this random code, an answer? Answers typically include some brief explanation of the issue and how/why the answer resolves it.